# ms access close form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know that `docmd.close` will close the current form but for some reason I have gotten it in my head that I want to be more explicit. What I do is `docmd.close acForm, me.name`.

Is that totally crazy or is there a good reason to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling DoCmd.Close with no argument closes the *active window*. Using the Me.Name syntax accounts for scenarios where the form in question is not the active window (example running hidden). Personally I prefer the explicit version as it does exactly what you want, whereas the implicit version will *probably* do what you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I knew there had to be a reason I was typing it out explicitly. thanks.